# Storing data in wordpress database from ajax call from different website

Tags: plugin-development, ajax, wpdb

What I am trying to do is that, I am providing users with embed code for videos...now with these embed codes I am sending a number, once the user watches the video, I am sending that number back to my website and storing in the database.

But the problem is the number is being saved but only when the user viewing the video is logged into wordpress.

```
<?php 

if(isset($_GET['user_number'])){$user_number = $_GET['user_number'];}

echo '<iframe src="http://localhost/deployment/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=h5p_embed&id=3" width="958" height="600" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe><script src="http://localhost/deployment/wp-content/plugins/h5p/h5p-php-library/js/h5p-resizer.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>';

 ?>

<script>
/*------------------------------
AJAX REQUEST TO SAVE USER NUMBER
--------------------------------*/
// window.onload = function(){
// var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].contentWindow.document;

     var srcstring = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].src;

     var id = /&id=(.*)/.exec(srcstring);

     var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

     xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost/deployment?user_number=<?php echo $user_number; ?>", true);

     xmlhttp.send();
 }
</script>
```